# What would cause a `mysql` command ran by Jenkins to use use `root` as its user?

Tags: mysql, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build job which uses several "execute shell" build steps.  The shells run a bash script which contains several calls to the `mysql` command.

The execute shell task looks something like:

```
./run-mysql-scripts.sh ${MYSQL_HOST} ${OTHER_PARAMETER} ...
```

The bash scripts contain several calls like:

```
mysql -h $1 < somescript.sql
```

The username is not specified by the scripts and so it should be inferred that it uses `jenkins@jenkinsserver` for mysql credentials.  This has worked for about a year.  However recently the builds have started generating errors that the script is attempting to use `root` as the mysql user:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'jenkinsserver' (using password: NO)
```

This has me baffled.  When adding a `whoami` command to the Jenkins job it returns `jenkins`, so the job is certainly running as the jenkins user.  When I login as the jenkins user and execute the same commands as the job it runs as expected, using the `jenkins@jenkinsserver` mysql auth.

My recollection is that this occurred when initially setting up Jenkins as well (about a year ago), but self-resolved quickly.  We have also had some large environmental changes that might have caused the issue--our Jenkins server was Ubuntu Server 13.10 but was recently updated to 14.04.1 LTS via a `do-release-upgrade`.  Other jobs and services on the server appear to be working normally.

What other possible reasons could result in a jenkins job using `root` as its user when calling `mysql`?

Comment: You should debug the situation and check if the MySQL client is actually running as the root user, or if it's trying to connect to the root account on the MySQL server (which could happen as a result of an explicit command line argument or possibly a preference file).

Comment: What preference files would be in play?  I could only find `.mysql-history`.  Logging in to bash as the `jenkins` user does not reproduce the issue--it's only when the job is executed via the jenkins service itself.